# Tabview do bootstrap ativado pelo hover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Criei um `tab` com `bootstrap` e ele troca as `tabs` ao clicar nos links gostaria que mudasse de uma `tab` a outro passando o mouse em cima é possível ? segue o código:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">buzz</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">references</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegue com evento `mouseover` e o método `.trigger("click")`:

```js
$(".nav-item").on("mouseover", function(){
   $("a", this).trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link active" href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="#buzz" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">buzz</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link" href="#references" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">references</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="profile">...</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="buzz">bbb</div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="references">ccc</div>
</div>
```